# How do I calculate angles to create vector offsets to define parallel paths?

Tags: c++, math, openframeworks

I have reference paths that are defined by a series of points. Given a starting point and additional points in a given direction, I need to effectively split the path created by the points into two distinct paths (directional) in a manner that allows me to draw and work with the two paths independently. The following screenshot shows 8 path examples. The "starting point" is the one with the white circle on it. If you orient yourself from the starting point towards the next point, then the path suggested by the red circles always should be to the "right" of the path defined by the given points.

In the screen, paths 2, 3, 5, 6, and 7 are correct. In paths 1, 4, and 8, essentially when the path starts on the right and moves left, then the *position* of the parallel path points are correct, but they are swapped in some instance (green where red should be, etc).

[image]

I'm somehow misusing `atan2()` (I think) to get the proper angle and or calculate the positions. For the first and last points, I'm calculating the angle to the adjacent point and the drawing the red and green path points at 90 degree offsets from that angle. For the points in the middle of the path, I'm looking at the angle to the previous point and the angle to the next point and placing the points in a manner that bisects the angles.

How do I properly calculate these angles to get the red and green parallel path points on the proper side of the reference line?

The problem likely is in `TestLine::calculateParallelPoints()`.

I used openFrameworks 0.90 for this. Here's the code:

**ofApp.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "TestLine.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

    public:
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();

    int sectors_wide;
    int sectors_tall;

    vector<TestLine> testLines;

};
```

**ofApp.cpp**

```
#include "ofApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup(){

    ofSetBackgroundColorHex(0x000000);

    sectors_wide = 4;
    sectors_tall = 2;

    TestLine t1 = TestLine(0,0,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.9,0.5));
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.8,0.6));
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.7,0.4));
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.6,0.6));
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.5,0.4));
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.4,0.4));
    t1.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.3,0.5));
    testLines.push_back(t1);


    TestLine t2 = TestLine(1,0,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.3,0.5)); //
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.4,0.4));
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.5,0.4));
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.6,0.6));
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.7,0.4));
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.8,0.6));
    t2.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.9,0.5));
    testLines.push_back(t2);

    TestLine t3 = TestLine(2,0,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t3.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.1,0.2));
    t3.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.7,0.4));
    t3.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.4,0.45));
    t3.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.6,0.5));
    t3.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.9,0.9));
    testLines.push_back(t3);

    TestLine t4 = TestLine(3,0,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t4.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.5,0.5));
    t4.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.9,0.5));
    t4.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.5,0.1));
    t4.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.1,0.1));
    t4.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.1,0.8));
    t4.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.8,0.6));
    testLines.push_back(t4);

    TestLine t5 = TestLine(0,1,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t5.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.4,0.4));
    t5.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.6,0.5));
    t5.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.8,0.4));
    testLines.push_back(t5);

    TestLine t6 = TestLine(1,1,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t6.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.7,0.1));
    t6.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.2,0.3));
    t6.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.7,0.5));
    testLines.push_back(t6);

    TestLine t7 = TestLine(2,1,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);
    t7.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.2,0.1));
    t7.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.7,0.3));
    t7.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.2,0.5));
    testLines.push_back(t7);

    TestLine t8 = TestLine(3,1,sectors_wide,sectors_tall);

    t8.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.8,0.5));
    t8.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.6,0.4));
    t8.raw_points.push_back(ofPoint(0.4,0.5));
    testLines.push_back(t8);

    // Convert raw points to real points in the grid space
    for (int i = 0; i < testLines.size(); i++) {
        testLines[i].processRawPoints();
        testLines[i].calculateParallelPoints();
    }


}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update(){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw(){

    ofSetBackgroundColorHex(0x000000);
    ofSetColor(255, 255, 255);

    for (int i = 0; i < testLines.size(); i++) {
        testLines[i].displayTestLine();
    }

}
```

**TestLine.h**

```
#include "ofMain.h"

class TestLine {
public:
    TestLine(float _x, float _y, int _sec_wide, int _sec_tall);

    void displayTestLine();
    void calculateParallelPoints();
    void processRawPoints();

    float x_coord;
    float y_coord;

    float x_min;
    float x_max;
    float y_min;
    float y_max;

    vector<float>   angles;
    vector<ofPoint> raw_points;
    vector<ofPoint> points;
    vector<ofPoint> forward_points;
    vector<ofPoint> reverse_points;

    ofPolyline line;
    ofPolyline forward_line;
    ofPolyline reverse_line;
};
```

**TestLine.cpp**

```
#include "TestLine.h"

TestLine::TestLine(float _x, float _y, int _sec_wide, int _sec_tall){
    x_coord = _x;
    y_coord = _y;

    int w = ofGetWindowWidth();
    int h = ofGetWindowHeight();

    float allowed_w = (float)w / _sec_wide;
    float allowed_h = (float)h / _sec_tall;

    x_min = x_coord * allowed_w;
    x_max = x_min   + allowed_w;

    y_min = y_coord * allowed_h;
    y_max = y_min   + allowed_h;




}

void TestLine::calculateParallelPoints(){
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ofVec2f v2 = points[i];
            ofVec2f v1 = points[i+1];

            float angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));
            angles.push_back(angle);

            cout << "Start: " << angle << endl;
        }

        if (i > 0 && i < points.size() - 1) {
            ofVec2f v1 = points[i];
            ofVec2f v2 = points[i-1];

            float back_angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));

            v2 = points[i];
            v1 = points[i+1];

            float front_angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));


            float final_angle = (back_angle + front_angle) / 2;

            cout << "BACK ANGLE: " << back_angle << ", FRONT ANGLE: " << front_angle << ", FINAL ANGLE: " << final_angle << endl;

            float prev_x = points[i-1].x;
            float prev_y = points[i-1].y;
            float this_x = points[i].x;
            float this_y = points[i].y;
            float next_x = points[i+1].x;
            float next_y = points[i+1].y;



            angles.push_back(final_angle);

        }

        if (i == points.size() - 1) {
            ofVec2f v1 = points[i];
            ofVec2f v2 = points[i-1];

            float angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));
            angles.push_back(angle);

            cout << "End: " << angle << endl;
        }

        line.addVertex(points[i]);
    }


    // Now using the points and the angles to calculate the forward and reverse points
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        float forward_angle = angles[i] + 90;
        float reverse_angle = angles[i] - 90;
        // cout << forward_angle << ", " << reverse_angle << endl;

        float forward_x = points[i].x + cos(ofDegToRad(forward_angle)) * 8;
        float forward_y = points[i].y + sin(ofDegToRad(forward_angle)) * 8;

        forward_points.push_back(ofPoint(forward_x, forward_y));

        float reverse_x = points[i].x + cos(ofDegToRad(reverse_angle)) * 8;
        float reverse_y = points[i].y + sin(ofDegToRad(reverse_angle)) * 8;

        reverse_points.push_back(ofPoint(reverse_x, reverse_y));

    }
}

void TestLine::processRawPoints(){
    for (int i = 0; i < raw_points.size(); i++) {
        float newx = ofMap(raw_points[i].x, 0, 1, x_min, x_max);
        float newy = ofMap(raw_points[i].y, 0, 1, y_min, y_max);
        points.push_back(ofPoint(newx,newy));
    }
}

void TestLine::displayTestLine(){

    ofSetColor(128,128,128);
    line.draw();

    ofSetColor(255, 255, 255);
    ofDrawCircle(points[0].x, points[0].y, 3);

    ofSetColor(255, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < forward_points.size(); i++) {
        ofDrawCircle(forward_points[i].x, forward_points[i].y, 2);
    }

    ofSetColor(0, 255, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < reverse_points.size(); i++) {
        ofDrawCircle(reverse_points[i].x, reverse_points[i].y, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up handling this with several conditional statements, though I feel there's probably a better way to handle it with trig. Here's the amended `TestLine.cpp` file.

**TestLine.cpp**

```
#include "TestLine.h"

TestLine::TestLine(float _x, float _y, int _sec_wide, int _sec_tall){
    x_coord = _x;
    y_coord = _y;

    int w = ofGetWindowWidth();
    int h = ofGetWindowHeight();

    float allowed_w = (float)w / _sec_wide;
    float allowed_h = (float)h / _sec_tall;

    x_min = x_coord * allowed_w;
    x_max = x_min   + allowed_w;

    y_min = y_coord * allowed_h;
    y_max = y_min   + allowed_h;
}

void TestLine::calculateParallelPoints(){
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ofVec2f v2 = points[i];
            ofVec2f v1 = points[i+1];

            float angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));
            angles.push_back(angle);

            cout << endl;
            cout << "Start: " << angle << endl;
        }

        if (i > 0 && i < points.size() - 1) {
            ofVec2f v1 = points[i];
            ofVec2f v2 = points[i-1];

            float back_angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));

            v2 = points[i];
            v1 = points[i+1];

            float front_angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));
            float final_angle = (back_angle + front_angle) / 2; // back_angle + front_angle


            float prev_x = points[i-1].x;
            float prev_y = points[i-1].y;
            float this_x = points[i].x;
            float this_y = points[i].y;
            float next_x = points[i+1].x;
            float next_y = points[i+1].y;

            // Here is the addition that addressed the problem.
            if ((prev_x > this_x && prev_y <= this_y && next_x < this_x && next_y < this_y) ||
                (prev_x > this_x && prev_y > this_y && next_x < this_x && next_y >= this_y)) {
                final_angle += 180;
            }

            cout << "BACK ANGLE: " << back_angle << ", FRONT ANGLE: " << front_angle << ", FINAL ANGLE: " << final_angle << endl;

            angles.push_back(final_angle);

        }

        if (i == points.size() - 1) {
            ofVec2f v1 = points[i];
            ofVec2f v2 = points[i-1];

            float angle = ofRadToDeg(atan2(v1.y - v2.y, v1.x - v2.x));
            angles.push_back(angle);

            cout << "End: " << angle << endl << endl;
        }

        line.addVertex(points[i]);
    }


    // Now using the points and the angles to calculate the forward and reverse points
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        float forward_angle = angles[i] + 90;
        float reverse_angle = angles[i] - 90;
        // cout << forward_angle << ", " << reverse_angle << endl;

        float forward_x = points[i].x + cos(ofDegToRad(forward_angle)) * 8;
        float forward_y = points[i].y + sin(ofDegToRad(forward_angle)) * 8;

        forward_points.push_back(ofPoint(forward_x, forward_y));

        float reverse_x = points[i].x + cos(ofDegToRad(reverse_angle)) * 8;
        float reverse_y = points[i].y + sin(ofDegToRad(reverse_angle)) * 8;

        reverse_points.push_back(ofPoint(reverse_x, reverse_y));

    }
}

void TestLine::processRawPoints(){
    for (int i = 0; i < raw_points.size(); i++) {
        float newx = ofMap(raw_points[i].x, 0, 1, x_min, x_max);
        float newy = ofMap(raw_points[i].y, 0, 1, y_min, y_max);
        points.push_back(ofPoint(newx,newy));
    }
}

void TestLine::displayTestLine(){

    ofSetColor(128,128,128);
    line.draw();

    ofSetColor(255, 255, 255);
    ofDrawCircle(points[0].x, points[0].y, 3);

    ofSetColor(255, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < forward_points.size(); i++) {
        ofDrawCircle(forward_points[i].x, forward_points[i].y, 2);
    }

    ofSetColor(0, 255, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < reverse_points.size(); i++) {
        ofDrawCircle(reverse_points[i].x, reverse_points[i].y, 2);
    }
}
```